# Set of items closest to the mean?

Tags: math, combinatorics

Given a set of N objects with assigned weights, how would we find the set of K objects that is closest to the average?  The average being sum(weights) / N.

Also, how could we compute the next set that is 2nd closest to the average, and continue on to the 3rd, 4th, etc.?

Comment: What are you computing the mean over? The subset or the full set? And what measure are you using to compare a subset with the average?

Answer (score 1):

1. Calculate the average
2. For each object calculate its difference
   from the average
3. Sort by this difference.
4. Take K objects from
   the top of the sorted list, and so on